# Terminology question about containment relation between sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, terminology, inclusion-exclusion, relations

I am not a mathematician and I need your help about naming a relation holding between subsets that are in a particular relation to one another. (For the fact that I am not a mathematician and hence my question will very likely seem trivial to you -- I apologize, but I really do not have anybody to ask for help about this...).

I will use the symbol ">" to indicate containment. I need to name (and ideally also describe) the structure where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are in a superset-subset relation just like their ingredients ($a,b$ and $x,y$, respectively) but at the same time only their bottom ingedients (that is, $b$ and $y$, respectively) are necessary ingredients for $\alpha$ and $\beta$ to exist (that's why I named $b$ and $y$ "proper subsets" in my original formulation of my question -- if I've done it in the wrong or a confusing way, I apologize, I have now modified it and hopefully made it clearer. I have also added an actual structure that I need to describe).

Assumptions:

$\alpha$ is $[a>b>\beta]$ and

$\beta$ is $[x>y]$

In the diagrams below, the arrow from $b$ (the bottom element of $\alpha$) indicates a pointer to $\beta$ (either its superset or subset).

I need to describe the relation that captures the following options to be true

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fwSBu.png)

... and which at the same time disallows the following options to be impossible:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2404s.png)

So, back to my question: is there terminology or a descritive formulation which I can apply to the relation holding between $a,b,x$ and $y$? 
Thanks!

Comment: You've explained what you mean by $>$ when it's written between two sets, as in $\mathbf a>\mathbf b$. But what does it mean when written between two statements, as in $[\mathbf a>\mathbf b]>[\mathbf x>\mathbf y]$? Or between a statement and a set, as in $[\mathbf a>\mathbf b]>\mathbf y$?

Comment: @AndreasBlass Thanks, Andreas. I've just modified my question, so it should be clearer now. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, it is customary to denote "inclusion" in the sense of subsets with $\subseteq$ and $\subset$ for a proper subset instead of $>$. $A \subset B \subset C$ is often visualized as below.

[image]

I feel like the answer you are looking for is simply "transitivity", formally as given as

$$ \forall a, \forall  b, \forall c: ( a \ast b ) \wedge ( b \ast c ) \rightarrow ( a \ast c )$$

where $a,b,c$ are sets, and $\ast$ is a relation. This means that, whenever the relation is true for $a$ and $b$, and for $b$ and $c$, then it is true for $a$ and $c$. It is true that set inclusion (that is, the subset relation $\subseteq$) is transitive, hence

$$ \forall a, \forall  b, \forall c: ( a \subseteq b ) \wedge ( b \subseteq c ) \rightarrow ( a \subseteq c )$$

This is why in my example above $A \subset C$ and in yours $y \subset x \subset b \subset a$ or as you wrote $[[a>b] > [x >y]]$.

I am not sure what you mean by "the composition of the structure $[\alpha > \beta]$. If you worry about $\alpha$ and $\beta$, again, having subsets, this is nothing to worry about. The relation is still simply transitive, without the need to further specify like "2-dimensional" or "double transitive".

Also, as has been pointed out in the comments, most of your statements do not make sense (formally). If you say that $[a > b]$ is a statement, then by writing $[[a > b] >y]$, you write that $y$ is contained in the statement, which does not make sense. Alternatively, you could write $a > b >y$ which is short hand for $a > b \wedge b > y$, meaning that $b$ is contained in $a$ and that $y$ is contained in $b$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! So, transitivity. I specifically was hesitant about using transitive closure before I asked my question, because what I really have to achieve with these structures is a formulation of an attested well-formedness of structures that include a particular cross-section between two sets $\alpha$ and $\beta$ (perhaps a simple set-theoretic notion is not what should be applied here at all). -- I have modified now my question to include an actual representation that I need to describe properly. Thanks!

Comment: I am glad I could help, but I am confused by your goal of a "formulation of an attested well-formedness of structures that include a particular cross-section". Since you say you are not a mathematician, what field of study does your question stem from exactly? Also, if the answer fully satisfies your question, please mark it as such in order to notify future visitors to the question.

Comment: Thanks! I've just pasted the images of the structures I'm interested in in my modified question.